# Checking Connection to server

Tags: c

I really have no idea how to implement this using C programming

- given the computer name and/or mac address of the server, how do i know if the client machine is connected to it
  the idea here is to know whether the client machine is connected to the server

I just started doing C programs, so please if you can give me a working sample or snippets that would be great and appreciate it. i will just have to modify it according to my need

thank you

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you want to know if the client is connected to the server?

Comment: we have a some programs that we need to control, these program can only run C modules, so when other user copy these programs, the program would run this C module/function to detect wether it is connected to our server

Answer (score 0):

set O_NONBLOCK flag to socket that pass to connect(). and call connect(). connect() will return without wait. then call select() for checking socket signaled for read/write.

Comment: thanks, if its not too much for you, can i have your answer in a procedure/function type